# Use CSS to select all P elements except for the one that comes before an ID

Tags: css

I need to use CSS to select all `<p>` elements except for the `<p>` that comes right before the div ID #one.

There will also be a varying number of `<p>` elements before #one so I won't be able to use nth-child.

```
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<div id="one">div</div>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
```

Ideally, I could do something like:

```
p:not(p+#one) {
    color: red;
}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work though.

Comment: Since there is no previous sibling selector yet, you're limited to using JavaScript